# Enterprise Gift registry is using default wishlist template (view.phtml) instead of gift registry template

Tags: template, enterprise-1.13

I'm using Magento Enterprise Gift Registry.
It is a comprehensive Enterprise core module and comes with serveral own templates. Also a wishlist view. This template provides an option to add a product from the wishlist into the gift registry.
But Magento is always using the default wishlist view (frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml) instead the one from enterprise gift registry.

I'm using my own theme in the enterprise package. System->Configuration->Design shows me "Enterprise" is set as package - so this supposed to be okay. Furthermore Gift registry is enabled.

Does anyone know what is causing the issue?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It is working as soon as you create a wishlist.
So if you don't have any active wishlist in your account it is using the default one.